# A simple counting step following a group by key is extremely slow in a DataFlow pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a DataFlow pipeline trying to build an index (key-value pairs) and compute some metrics (like a number of values per key). The input data is about 60 GB total, stored on GCS and the pipeline has about 126 workers allocated. Per Stackdriver all workers have about 6% CPU utilization.

The pipeline seems to make no progress despite having 126 workers and based on the wall time the bottleneck seems to be a simple counting step that follows a group by. While all other steps have on average less than 1 hour spent in them, the counting step took already 50 days of the wall time. There seems to be no helpful information all warnings in the log.

The counting step was implemented following a corresponding step in the WordCount example:

```
def count_keywords_per_product(self, key_and_group):
    key, group = key_and_group
    count = 0
    for e in group:
        count += 1

    self.stats.product_counter.inc()
    self.stats.keywords_per_product_dist.update(count)

    return (key, count)
```

The preceding step "Group keywords" is a simple beam.GroupByKey() transformation.

Please advise what might be the reason and how this can be optimized.

```
Current resource metrics:
Current vCPUs    126
Total vCPU time      1,753.649 vCPU hr
Current memory   472.5 GB
Total memory time    6,576.186 GB hr
Current PD   3.08 TB
Total PD time    43,841.241 GB hr
Current SSD PD   0 B
Total SSD PD time    0 GB hr
Total Shuffle data processed     1.03 TB
Billable Shuffle data processed      529.1 GB
```

The pipeline steps including the counting one can be seen below:
[image]

Comment: GCP support told me that re-iteration of grouping results are not cached in python. This might cause issues similar to the reported problem. As workaround users could use java sdk, or update their user code to reduce re-iteration. In my case, the only form of re-iteration that I have is that the PCollection containing GroupBy results gets written to a file and in a parallel branch used to compute the counters.

Comment: Here is a solution that worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/55527648/3745936. TL;DR; do not attempt to reuse GroupBy output in Python SDK for Apache Beam. It is either a bug or behavior that should be documented and prevented by the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The best way of having a sum per key here is to use a combine operation. The reason is that it can alleviate the problem of having hot keys.

Try replacing your `GroupByKey + ParDo` with a `beam.combiners.Count.PerKey`, or a similar combine transform that suits your use case.

Comment: Pablo thank you for your feedback. I will definitely try it and post the result here.  However, the number of items per key in my pipeline is not exceeding a few thousand. And the approach I used for counting was taken from the official WordCount example. Could you please elaborate a bit about what's going on under the hood? Shouldn't DataFlow at least issue a warning and downscale when it is running all available workers at 5% CPU utilization and make no progress. Is there a cookbook on how to properly diagnose issues like this?

Comment: Another question, how to output the result of GroupByKey as a collection of key-value pairs without hitting this problem? My current approach was to feed the GroupByKey collection to beam.FlatMap that does formatting of each key-value pair, then feed it to WriteToText. Because it is also a GroupbByKey + ParDo, I assume it can be vulnerable to the same issue.

Comment: Adding a combiner (result_of_group_by_key | CombineValues(CountCombineFn())) didn't help. Still observing the same symptoms. The counting step appears as "Part running", makes no progress and all workers stay at 5% utilization. The preceding GroupBy step (it's output is also used by other transformation) was still running but based on the wall time it looks like it is using very few VMs, which makes me think is the root cause of the problem... I will try to insert a reshuffle() before the GroupBy to see if that helps but I thought I am not supposed to inject such "optimizations" myself.

Comment: Reshuffle didn't change anything. GroupBy is still "part running" with 5% worker CPU utilization.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Will take a look tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you, Pablo. Here is the id of the original job that took 23h+ before I canceled it "analyze-search-test-3ebcd51e64-reshuffle-shuffleservice-full". Here is a job with a combiner and more reshuffle-s " analyze-search-prod-2f82af3b78-reshuffle-shuffleservice-combine-full". And here is a job I am currently running with the "shuffle service" disabled (thought it might be a bottleneck) "analyze-search-prod-b8bc0fe1a5-no-reshuffle-shuffleservice-combine-full"

Comment: Pablo, all transformations succeeded under 2 hours after dividing the pipeline in 2 and running them separately. Instead of reusing GroupBy output for 2 transformations, I save the results to the file first and then in the second pipeline load them from the file. My assumption was that by computing GroupBy once I actually optimize the pipeline, however, as observed in my case, it kills the performance. Could you please confirm that reusing GroupBy was never meant to work in Dataflow? Shouldn't it be documented? I also tried reshuffle, combiner and disabling shuffle service but it didn't help.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, and posted my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57545513/dataflow-apache-beam-python-job-stuck-at-group-by-step , @kpax can you help me here?