# Dataflow Apache beam Python job stuck at Group by step

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam, dataflow

I am running a dataflow job, which readed from BigQuery and scans around `8 GB of data and result in more than 50,000,000 records.` Now at group by step I want to group based on a key and one column need to be concatenated . But After concatenated size of concatenated column becomes more than 100 MB that why I have to do that group by in dataflow job because that group by can not be done in `Bigquery level due to row size limit of 100 MB.`

Now the dataflow job scales well when reading from BigQuery but stuck at Group by Step , I have 2 version of dataflow code, but both are stucking at group by step. `When I checked the stack driver logs, it says, processing stuck at lull for more than 1010 sec time(similar kind of message) and Refusing to split GroupedShuffleReader <dataflow_worker.shuffle.GroupedShuffleReader object at 0x7f618b406358> kind of message`

[image]
[image]

I expect the group by state to be completed within 20 mins but is stuck for more than 1 hours and never gets finished

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the thing myself.
Below are the 2 changes that I did in my pipeline:
1. I added a Combine function just after the Group by Key, see screenshot[image]

2. since the Group by key when running on multiple worker, does a lot of network traffic exchange, and by default the network we use, does not allow the inter network communication, so I have to create a firewall rule to allow traffic from one worker to another worker i.e. ip range to network traffic.